# Variable Not Showing When Function Called Early In Script

Tags: php

Any help is appreciated. I cannot seem to get the value of $sum if I call showSum() before the function...

EXAMPLE 1: (this works fine)

```
[main code here]

$sum = $valueObtainedAfterWhileLoop;

function showSum(){
global $sum;

return $sum;
}
echo getSum();
```

---

EXAMPLE 2: (this does not work - no error is returned, but no value is printed to the screen)

```
echo getSum();

[main code here]

$sum = $valueObtainedAfterWhileLoop;

function showSum(){
global $sum;

return $sum;
}
```

I need to use the value of $sum at the top of the page. What can I do?

---

Comment: why you need $sum at the top of the page?

Comment: I need it it calculate more totals which are displayed in a tabular layout.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely nothing. The variable has not been assigned to yet, so there's no value to use. Try calculating it in the function instead.